# How to get ip address of current user in Lightning component

Tags: lightning

We are converting our visualforce pages to Lightning component. We were getting the ip address of the current user from visualforce page standard headers. But we cant use the same in Lightning controller.

Does anyone know any solution in getting ip address in Lightning controller other than passing parameter from visualforce page?

Comment: Currently you might not be able to get the true client ip using ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders() as it requires VF pages, and i belive this falls in line  with the idea exchange link https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DqjTAAS . Making a client side api call to external api's is not option as client side calls are blocked by Content-security-policy https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_api_calls_platform.htm . Hence you have work-around this issue by getting the ip from the server side and pass from VF or store it in custom setting.

Comment: Worth trying it in javascript
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/how-to-get-clients-ip-address-using-javascript

Comment: https://sfdcian.com/salesforce-get-ip-address-of-community-user-guest-and-logged-in-customer-user/

Answer (score 5):

I also had this requirement but initially wasn't quite sure how to get the AuthSession info recommended here.  Here is the code I ended up with that returned my external IP correctly:

**Apex controller:**

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String getExternalIp() {
    Map<String,String> currentSessionAttributes = Auth.SessionManagement.getCurrentSession();
    String ip = currentSessionAttributes.get('SourceIp');
    return ip;
}
```

**Lightning Component:**

```
var action = component.get('c.getExternalIp');
  action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
  var state = response.getState();
  if (state === "SUCCESS") {
       console.log('External IP is: ' + response.getReturnValue());
  }
  else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
       alert('result incomplete');
  }
  else if (state === "ERROR") {
       var errors = response.getError();
       if (errors) {
           if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                 console.log("Error message: " + errors[0].message);
           }
        } else {
            console.log("Unknown error");
            }
   }
 });

 $A.enqueueAction(action);
```

Comment: This is a better method than querying the AuthSession object because there can be multiple "active" sessions at a time.  In theory, a user could have 2 concurrent active (WHERE IsCurrent = true) sessions at the same time from different IPs.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to query *AuthSession.SourceIp*
[User Sessions in docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_user_session_info.htm&type=5)

put it in 
@auraEnabled method inside apex controller

call backed action from lightning controller

[contrllers server actions docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm)

[force base blog](https://force-base.com/2016/12/12/learn-how-to-call-an-apex-class-from-a-lightning-component/)

Answer (score 1):

If someone wants a native Javascript solution, you can get it done by making an `ipAddressComponent`

Component:

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute type="String" name="ipAddress"></aura:attribute>

    <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}" />
    {!v.ipAddress}

</aura:component >
```

Js:

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const url='https://api.ipify.org/';
        Http.open("GET", url);
        Http.send();
        Http.onreadystatechange=(e)=>{
            console.log(Http.responseText); // This prints Ip address
            component.set("v.ipAddress", Http.responseText);
        }
    }
})
```

Just make sure you add `https://api.ipify.org/` to your [CSP Trusted Site](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=csp_trusted_sites.htm&type=5).