# How to get the Ip address of current user in apex of a lightning page

Tags: lightning

Earlier for a VF page, We were getting the ip address of the current user from visualforce page standard headers. But we cant use the same in Lightning controller.

Does anyone know any solution to get the IP address in apex of a lightning page?

Comment: This [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/145145/how-to-get-ip-address-of-current-user-in-lightning-component) was previously asked and looks like you can leverage [Source IP](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_user_session_info.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 5):

Can you just not query the AuthSessoin object and there you can find the source IP address.

Link to the document - [AuthSession](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_AuthSession.htm)

```
SELECT Id, SourceIp FROM AuthSession WHERE UsersId = :UserInfo.getUserId ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: How would this work if the use case was to get this info from a public website hosted on Salesforce Sites? I don't think that this would work (as the public users won't be authenticated). I guess using Google Analytics or a similar tool like Cloudflare Web Analytics would have to be used.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the best way to do it is:

```
 public static String getUserIPAddress() {
    Map<String, String> session = Auth.SessionManagement.getCurrentSession();
    return session.get('SourceIp');
}
```

Documentation:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Auth_SessionManagement.htm