# Get IP Address from LWC Component

Tags: lightning-web-components

Is there an elegant, non-hack way to get the user's IP address from within an LWC component?  (Not an Aura component).

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that you want to get the external public IP address and not the local one, the basic way would be to adapt the code from [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/145145/how-to-get-ip-address-of-current-user-in-lightning-component)

exampleIP.html

```
<template>
    {ip.data}
</template>
```

exampleIP.js

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import getExternalIp from '@salesforce/apex/LWC_Utils.getExternalIp';
export default class ExampleIP extends LightningElement {
    @wire(getExternalIp) ip;
}
```

LWC_Utils.cls

```
public class LWC_Utils {
      @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
      public static String getExternalIp() {
          return Auth.SessionManagement.getCurrentSession().get('SourceIp');
      } 
}
```

And by "basic" I mean that this example is "assuming all goes well", but you should actually control that there are no errors coming back from the class, and that it can be called (for example that it does not fail because the Profile does not have access to the class and the critical update that checks that is active)

Comment: Excellent, Sergio.  Thank you very much!

Comment: I guess this doesn't work with Community users, alternatives for community user https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/325921/getting-community-users-ip-address-via-apex ?